# Media Query in Email - does it require a certain meta tag?

Tags: css, email, responsive-design, media-queries, meta-tags

I've built an email that uses media queries to resize from 2 columns to 1 when the viewing device width decreases. When I tested using litmus.com by uploading my code, the email resized on Android, iPhone and Windows phone perfectly!!

However, after I copied my code to the editor in the email service that will be used to send out the email and tested again by sending a message from the email service to Litmus, the mobile versions didn't resize as intended.

Viewing the source on this second test showed that my email service strips out all code above the styles, and only includes this meta tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```

Could deleting the "HandheldFriendly" meta tag be causing my media query not to work? Is there something else that looks like a problem here?

Here's my header code -

```
<!doctype html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="True" />

<style type="text/css">
.ReadMsgBody {width: 100%; background-color: #ffffff;}
.ExternalClass {width: 100%; background-color: #ffffff;}
body     {width: 100%; background-color: #ffffff; margin:0; 
    padding:0; -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;}
html {width: 100%; }
table {border-collapse: collapse;}

@media screen and (max-device-width: 1000px)  {
body[yahoo] .deviceWidth {width:440px!important}    
body[yahoo] .center {text-align: center!important;}  
body[yahoo] .footerLinks { width:32%; margin-bottom:40px}
    }

@media screen and (max-device-width: 479px) {
body[yahoo] .deviceWidth {width:280px!important}    
body[yahoo] .center {text-align: center!important;}  
body[yahoo] .footerLinks { width:32%; margin-bottom:40px}
    }
</style>

</head>
```

Any help would be wonderful - thank you!!

Update: here is the altered header code I can see when I view the source of a test sent from my email service to my account.

```
Content-type: text/html;
charset="ISO-8859-1"
Content-transfer-encoding: quoted-printable

<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv=3D"Content-Type" content=3D"text/html; charset=3Dutf-8">
</head>
<body>
<style type=3D"text/css"><!--
.ReadMsgBody {width: 100%; background-color: #ffffff;}
.ExternalClass {width: 100%; background-color: #ffffff;}
body     {width: 100%; background-color: #ffffff; margin:0; padding:0; -webki=
    t-font-smoothing: antialiased;}
html {width: 100%; }
table {border-collapse: collapse;}

@media screen and (max-device-width: 1000px)  {
 body[yahoo] .deviceWidth {width:440px!important}   
        body[yahoo] .center {text-align: center!important;} =20
        body[yahoo] .footerLinks { width:32%; margin-bottom:40px}
        }

@media screen and (max-device-width: 479px) {
        body[yahoo] .deviceWidth {width:280px!important}    
        body[yahoo] .center {text-align: center!important;} =20
        body[yahoo] .footerLinks { width:32%; margin-bottom:40px}
        }
--></style>
```

Comment: We need to see exactly what the source looks like when this is _not_ working.

Comment: @thealexbaron, thanks for the response! I've added the altered header code above, any ideas would be very much appreciated!